# Mobile Wallet Adapter - failed to send transaction: Transaction signature verification failure

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter

**Describe the bug**
Mobile Wallet Adapter transaction error.

**Expected behavior**
failed to send transaction: Transaction signature verification failure

- OS: Android 13
- Browser Chrome Mobile 109.0

**Smartphone (please complete the following information):**

- Device: Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra 5G

**Additional context**
After clicking the select wallet button with the Chrome browser, approval is obtained from the phantom wallet.
Then it redirects to the chrome browser.
When there is a transaction made in the browser, it connects to the phantom wallet again and the confirmation screen opens.
After the confirmation is finished, the process encounters an error as follows.

failed to send transaction: Transaction signature verification failure.

This error only occurs when using the Mobile Wallet Adapter. I don't have any problems while operating with the browser in the Phantom.

Comment: try updating phantom on the mobile device to the latest version if you haven't already

Comment: The problem does not only apply to the phantom wallet.
I think it could be a valid issue for the mobile adapter. The same issue continues to occur when I try with my Solflare wallet.

The problem only happens on android devices. This issue does not apply to iPhone devices.